# Separate two batteries getting charged by one charger with diodes?

Tags: digital-logic, dc, battery-charging, dc-motor, raspberry-pi

I've got a robot that I use two batteries on. One of the batteries power the servos and engines and the other is for the digital boards.

- The servos need 5 V.
- The control board and LCD run on 5 V.
- The engines use 12 V.

Both batteries are identical 12 V packs (3x 18650) each with their own BMS.

The robot is using DC-DC 12 V to 5 V step down converters to get appropriate voltages to the different parts.

I want to be able to charge both batteries from one 12 V source but also keep them isolated so the motors battery cant take juice of the digital battery and vice versa.

Can I use diodes on the 4 lines (2+, 2 Ground) coming from the single charger two for each battery to accomplish this separation?

Should I put a diode on each side of each battery or for example only on the ground or volt?

Is there a better way?

The lines between the Arduino and the controller don't link the batteries in any way. But the common charged does which is the problem I want to solve.

[image: Schematic]

Comment: What kind of circuit do you have in mind? I really can't envision a case where this power flow problem can be solved with a diode, but I also don't know everything nor have in my head what you have in yours – please draw a schematic explaining what you have in mind!!

Comment: thanks for the schematic, but *where* do you want to fit in the diodes?

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you are asking how to charge a 3s2p pack.  The better answers will involve [battery balancing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battery_balancing).  A process which, in the most rigorous examples, involves extra wires to every battery terminal and a processor controlled charger.

Likely, the simplicity of using 2 independent chargers on 2 independent 3s1p packs outweighs the complexity of balancing a single 3s2p pack.  Even more so as the 2 independent 3s1p packs will have different power demands and therefor different charging histories.

Comment: each 3s1p battery pack has BMS and so have to barrel jacks coming from them for input and output. the BMS lets me charge them together but the cables also makes it behave like a 3s2p pack which is bad as the engines introduce noise and also can reset the digital board if they stall.

Comment: Even starting at the same state-of-charge, there is no guarantee it would be the same when resuming charging: agree that charging with an independent current looks called for. Not necessarily with separate mains power supplies - one notebook PS might do nicely for both chargers.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot isolate the voltage sources using the diodes because what will end up happening is that 1 voltage source(the lower one) will source much less current than the other voltage source(the higher one).

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand function of each component.

1. BMS, protect battery Over-charge, over-discharge and over current. Some BMS also balance cells.
2. Balancer,(Passive or active) Passive balancer will discharge over-voltage cell while charging to prevent over-charge. Active balancer will charge lower voltage cells with higher voltage one to make all cell equal voltage and extend battery run-time also prevent overcharge while charging.
3. Charger, provide constant current or constant voltage to charge battery (work like regulator)
4. Power supply, just supply voltage and current for charger like normal PSU did.

If you plug PSU to battery directly, you just put a lot of current through battery cell which could kill battery and causing fire. (Note: BMS not help limiting charging current)

What you want to do, You need one PSU connect to 2 chargers which each charger connect to battery. As both battery have common ground you can do this.